# how to move a "camera" to left/right of the direction the player is facing

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Hello i'am making a opengl fps game. Right now i'am making the movement , i can move forwards and backwards but not to the sides.

i've played around with it but still can't figure out the problem.

```
newPos.z += (float)cos(yaw * M_PI / 180);
newPos.x += (float)sin(yaw * M_PI / 180);

newPos.z -= (float)cos(yaw * M_PI / 180);
newPos.x -= (float)sin(yaw * M_PI / 180);
```

This is how i move forwards and backwards. The first bit moves me forwards and the second backwards.

Comment: Have you tried tinkering with newPos.y?

Comment: no, just x and z.

Comment: What happens if you only increase z? Going up/down? Going forward/backward?

Comment: What happens if you only increase x? Going up/down? Going forward/backward?

Comment: just moves in x or z axis.

Comment: And left-right would be your y-axis ?

Comment: y-axis is up/down

Comment: And the shown code only moves you forward backward and not at all left/right?

Comment: it moves you to the direction you are facing

Comment: You need to be more aware of your grid. Can you draw it, draw an arrow with direction and location. Draw the angle "yaw" you are using? Draw the X and Z elements of your forward. See the reason for your trigonometry formulas.

Comment: If not, swap `x` and `z` in your code and see what happens.

Comment: So you find my answer helpful?

Comment: yes i do find it helpful

Comment: @ENx2 Then go press the green tick on the left of the answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more aware of your grid.
Draw it, draw an arrow with direction and location.
Draw the angle "yaw" you are using.
Draw the X and Z elements of your "forward".
See the reason for your trigonometry formulas.

If you cannot do that, swap `x` and `z` in your code and see what happens